# Android null pointer exception with EditText

Tags: java, android

I have got this error and my application stops running

> va.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference

---

when I click on the button next please tell me what to do instead in order to check that the fields are empty

```
  if ( ( lastName.getText().toString().matches("")) || ( firstName.getText().toString().matches("") ) ||
                    ( id.getText().toString().matches("") ) || ( email.getText().toString().matches("") ) ||
                            ( phoneNumber.getText().toString().matches("") ) )
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please, post a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: one of your `EditText`s is `null` (`lastName` or `firstName` or ..) Check where you assign values to them for mistakes (usually something like `lastName = findById(R.id.something)`.

Answer (score 0):

with out more to go on, I would suspect that you're calling getText() on a null object so before you call getText() ensure the object references ar not null;

```
 if ( ( lastName == null || ( firstName == null ) ||
                ( id == null ) || ( email == null) ||
                        ( phoneNumber == null ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use TextUtils.isEmpty(lastName.getText())
it is a better function which checks for null or empty strings.